# The element neighbors in binary search

Tags: python

I read two binary search template in leetcodes 
[Explore - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/binary-search/125/template-i/938/)

The standard Template I

```py
def binarySearch(nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return -1

    left, right = 0, len(nums) - 1
    while left <= right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if nums[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif nums[mid] < target:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid - 1

    # End Condition: left > right
    return -1
```

> Summarize the key attributes:
>
> 1. Most basic and elementary form of Binary Search
> 2. Search Condition can be determined without comparing to the element's neighbors (or use specific elements around it)
> 3. No post-processing required because at each step, you are checking to see if the element has been found. If you reach the end, then you know the element is not found

Reference to attribute 2:

> Search Condition can be determined without comparing to the element's neighbors (or use specific elements around it)

I does not get its ideas.

There exist condition `while left <= right` , how come to state that `without comparing to the elements neighbors`

Template II

```py
def binarySearch(nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return -1

    left, right = 0, len(nums)
    while left < right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if nums[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif nums[mid] < target:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid

    # Post-processing:
    # End Condition: left == right
    if left != len(nums) and nums[left] == target:
        return left
    return -1
```

> **Key Attributes:**
>
> ---
>
> - An advanced way to implement Binary Search.
> - Search Condition needs to access element's immediate right neighbor
> - Use element's right neighbor to determine if condition is met and decide whether to go left or right
> - Gurantees Search Space is at least 2 in size at each step
> - Post-processing required. Loop/Recursion ends when you have 1 element left. Need to assess if the remaining element meets the condition.

What's the `element`, is it not mid?

I might get stuck in, could you please given hints to help out?

Comment: For the first one search condition can be determined when `if nums[mid] == target` meets so I think that's why it says "without comparing to the element's neighbors".

Comment: The template II has the same first search condition @knh190

Comment: I think the code itself is much clearer than the description. The second one is comparing target with either `mid+1` (left) or `mid` (right) while the first one involves comparing `mid-1`(right), `mid` and `mid+1` (left).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @knh190, the description is very unclear here, I have read serval times to get his idea. it is more useful to focus on code.

you can undstand code in your way, not obey his rule.

And a another suggestion, there are too many implementation for one algorithm, so just choose the most familiar version, you will get confused by too many variation version,  maybe just some coding hobbits. Or, it's really the best performance and most concise solution, but it's not the suitable for you.

For the first Question, "There exist condition `while left <= right`, how come to state that `without comparing to the elements neighbors`":
I think his statement is ambiguous here, I think you have got his idea, because `while left <= right`, so we don't need to `without comparing to the elements neighbors`.
in comparison, you can see the second verion, `while left < right`, so he should comparse the elements neighbors `nums[left] == target` outside the loop.

For the second Question, "What's the element, is it not `mid`?":
`element` represent the current member in `nums`, in loop, it refer to 'nums[mid]', and outside loop `element` refer to `nums[left]`

I hope I understand his meanings, and your meanings, and let you understand my meanings. : )

Comment: I finally got his idea. when update as `hi=mid-1`, mid is exactly the true mid(or the left one if even';  when update as `hi = mid`, mid is not the true mid, it is the right to the true mid. so in templeate III, `lo = mid` and `hi = mid`, he states to search the left neighbor and right neighbor, since they are left and right to the true mid.